# position of cell with orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with 5 rows with each row consisting of 3 cells in each row in Portrait orientation on the view. In landscape, it has 3 x 4 cells, with half visible 4th row. For example, if a cell index is 5, it appears as below:

Portrait - second row, second cell.
Landscape - Second row, first cell.

If for instance, in Portrait mode, the collection view is scrolled down with an offset. And if the orientation is changed to Landscape, is it possible to

1) find out the exact position of the cell after applying appropriate content offset?
2) find out the scroll offset in the new orientation?

I will need the position without reloading the view in the orientation. By position, I mean the center of the cell. And the scroll offset too?

Would it be possible? Would it be a right approach, if I load the contents on an offscreen collection view and scroll to the cell to find its position?

Please help!!

Comment: can you post some screen shots

Comment: I can post a screenshot but just curious on how it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a work around here.

I am trying to reload the collection view with the change in orientation and scroll to the selected cell at scroll position UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically. Now, I know the position of the cell according to the cell index.